# Problem setting edges in vis-network with typescript

Tags: vis.js, visnetwork

I'm following the Dynamic Dataset example from vis and I'm getting a typescript error when I try to set edges.

I just have an edge array that looks like:

```
edgesArray = [
 { from: 1, to: 3 },
 { from: 1, to: 2 },
 { from: 2, to: 4 },
 { from: 3, to: 5 },
 ]
```

and I'm setting the data as

```
let data = {
  nodes: new vis.DataSet(nodesArray),
  edges: new vis.DataSet(edgesArray)
}
```

The error I'm getting is in the edges.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(options?: DataSetInitialOptions<"id">): DataSet<Partial<Record<"id", string | number>>, "id">', gave the following error.
    Type '{ from: number; to: number; } []' has no properties in common with type 'DataSetInitialOptions<"id">'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(data: Partial<Record<"id", string | number>>[], options?: DataSetInitialOptions<"id">): DataSet<Partial<Record<"id", string | number>>, "id">', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ from: number; to: number; } []' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Record<"id", string | number>>[]'.
```

I'm using version 5.2.4 of vis-network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is standard TS behavior. You're trying to assign type A into B but they have nothing in common. DataSet can accept items that have optional id. However your edges have no ids and TS simply says you're doing something wrong.

Solution one:

```
import { Edge } from "vis-network";

const edgesArray: Edge[] = [
    { from: 1, to: 3 },
    { from: 1, to: 2 },
    { from: 2, to: 4 },
    { from: 3, to: 5 },
];
```

Solution two:

```
const edgesArray = [
    { id: undefined, from: 1, to: 3 },
    { from: 1, to: 2 },
    { from: 2, to: 4 },
    { from: 3, to: 5 },
];
```

Solution three:

```
const edgesArray: { id?: undefined, from: number, to: number }[] = [
    { from: 1, to: 3 },
    { from: 1, to: 2 },
    { from: 2, to: 4 },
    { from: 3, to: 5 },
];
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if it would be possible to update the examples with typescript examples as well

Comment: You can create a PR if you have time. Help is always appreciated.